# I have these weird dark smears on my model when set to smooth shading

Tags: modeling, shaders, vertices

[image: Weird blurring effect on a non-textured model]

I have a weird effect on my model for this retopology im doing for a character. It looks like someone smudges some black along some vertices and I can't fix it and don't want to use the auto smooth shading option (which seems to get rid of it for some reason).

[image: Weird blurring with vertices viewable]

Is is something with my vertice or edge positioning? I can't find anyone with the same problem.

Comment: Could you check if you have duplicate vertices/edges, then merge by distance ? It seems that the normals are discontiguous along the "vertical central line" in your picture.

Comment: Also make sure that you don't have inverted normals, select all and press Shift N to recalculate, if it still doesn't work please share this part of your object